# how to retrieve text from an xml

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to try an retrieve the name of a hotel (in this example the hotel is called 'Test Hotel'), but I am unsure how to do it because I believe to get a @node it's using @ but how do I retrieve a text?

Below is the xml:

```
<xxx xmlns:soap="xxx" xmlns:xsi="xxx" xmlns:xsd="xxx">
   <xxx>
      <xxxxmlns="xxx">
         <AvailabilityRS Url="xxx" IntCode="xxx">
            <Results>
               <HotelResult Code="xxx"DestinationZone="xxx">
                  <HotelInfo>
                     <Name>Test Hotel</Name>
```

Below is the script:

```
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getProperty("Response").getValue()
def parsedxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)



def hotelName = parsedxml.'soap:Body'.HotelAvailResponse[0].xxx[0].Results[0].xxxx[0].xxx[0].Name[0].toString()
```

Comment: Do you need to assert the hotel name? is it a list of hotels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `toString()`, you should be able to just use `text()`

```
def hotelName = parsedxml.Body
                         .HotelAvailResponse
                         .AvailabilityRS
                         .Results
                         .HotelResult
                         .HotelInfo
                         .Name.text()
```